# I am having issues uploading my app to Google playstore

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to upload my flutter app to playstore, but it got rejected, I got an email like this below

[image: Rejected App Mail]

This is how my pubspec.yaml file look like

[image: pubspec.yaml]

my Androidmanifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I was thinking maybe the `permission_handler` is the cause of the rejection,
but based on my research online, I believe it suppose to go through since I added this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Comment: Yes it is probably about the install packages permission. According to the mail, Google thinks it is not related with your app, and if you don't use this permission you can try to remove that permission and upload again.

Comment: Your email from Google Play basically mentions the issue with your app. You have to remove the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission (by removing the line in the manifest which you've mentioned). Does your app needs this permission in order to be functional and are you sure `permission_handler` absolutely requires it?

Comment: @batuhand I got the same email before adding this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>.  What can I do after removing this permission and still get same email for app rejection

Comment: @Vym I got the same email before adding this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>.  What can I do after removing this permission and still get same email for app rejection

Comment: Just basically remove that line from AndroidManifest file

Comment: @batuhand My app still got rejected for same  REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission issue after removing that line from AndroidManifest file. And I searched the entire folder for the usage of it, and there was none.

Comment: You can argue about it with Google Playstore

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the Google Playstore message.
They are telling you that your app shouldn't use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

So you have two options:

1. Either Remove this permission request from your app or
2. argue with the Google Playstore support about why your app really needs this permission. They list a few allowed cases (web browsing as a core functionality for example)

Comment: I was not using this permissopn before and I got the same mail before adding it, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>